# ajaxcontroltoolkit CascadingDropDown call method when control populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a CascadingDropDown control in my page. I want to do some jquery actions when the dropdown is populated. according to the [documentation](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/CascadingDropDown#populated) , there is a event called (populated) for  that purpose.
I added that code in my page:

```
function raise_populated() {
    alert()
}
```

and here is how i use the dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="listcat" runat="server" required></asp:DropDownList>
            <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlisteCategorie" TargetControlID="listcat"  PromptText='Catégories'
                ServicePath="../Webservice/CategorieService.asmx"  ServiceMethod="GetCategories"  Category="IDCATS" runat="server" LoadingText="Chargement..."></ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>
```

the `raise_populated` never fires.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1196704.aspx?Client%20Side%20Events%20with%20CascadingDropDown%20after%20data%20load%20)

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
    var cdd = $find("behaviorIDofCDD");
    cdd.add_populated(onPopulated);
}
function onPopulated()
{
    //any function to be called
}
```